# Registrar datos en Mysql con c#

Tags: mysql, c#, base-de-datos, conexión

Estoy intentando crear un código para poder registrar datos en MySql con C#. La conexion con la base de datos es correcta. Sin embargo me sale un error compatibilidad a la hora del registro. Tengo las siguientes versiones:

- Visual Studio 2019:  16.9.3
- .NET Framework: 4.8.4
- MySQL Workbench:  8.0
- MySql.Net Connector: 8.0.23

He probado usando el conector en versión 6.8.9 y me da el mismo error.

La especificación que me sale del error es la siguiente:

> "Gravedad Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
> Advertencia       La referencia principal "MySql.Data, Version=8.0.23.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL" no se pudo resolver porque tiene una
> dependencia indirecta en el ensamblado "Ubiety.Dns.Core,
> Version=2.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d",
> que se compiló con la versión de .NET Framework
> ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2". Esta es una versión posterior a la
> versión de .NET Framework de destino actual
> ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5". "

Comment: Tienes un problema de versiones. Hay dos opciones: o usar una version mas antigua del conector mysql, o subir la version de framework de tu proyecto a 4.5.2

Comment: He creado otro proyecto con la version del framework 4.5.2 y me ha funcionado, muchas gracias